# How can I instantiate class only if argument passed is string?

Tags: python, class, instance

I created a class 'Stage' and want instantiate it only if argument passed to **init**(arg)

```
#example code

class Stage:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if type(arg) == str:
            #create object
        else:
            #do not create object

#main:
# entry = input()

obj = Stage(entry)

if obj:
    print("created")         # if entry is string
else:
    print("not created")     # if entry is float
```

Comment: SORRY:     i want to instantiate it only if arg is a string. Case not, do not create the object.

Comment: Nit: the object has already been *created* by the time `__init__` is called; the question is whether you continue to *initialize* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise an exception:

```
def __init__(self, arg):
    if not isinstance(arg, str):
        raise TypeError("Stage.__init__ called with a non-str value: %r" % (arg,))

    # continue initializing the object
```

However, consider whether it the value really needs to *be* a `str`, or just something that can be turned into a `str`:

```
def __init__(self, arg):
    arg = str(arg)
    # ...
```

---

If you want to avoid *creating* the instance altogether, you need to override `__new__`, not `__init__` (with some of the previous advice folded in):

```
class Stage:
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        try:
            arg = str(arg)
        except ValueError:
            raise TypeError("Could not convert arg to str: %r" % (arg, ))

        return super().__new__(cls, arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the type of argument before instantiating your object. Also consider using `isinstance` to check for a type, instead of `type`

```
class Stage:
    def __init__(self, arg):
       pass

if isinstance(str, entry):
    obj = Stage(entry)
else:
    raise TypeError('A str-type is required as an argument to the constructor')
```

Comment: Hi @JoãoVitor Glad to help! If the answer helped you, please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to answer! Also consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize an object with that condition, but you can throw an error

```
class Stage:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if not isinstance(arg, str):
            raise TypeError("non-str value: %r was passed, str type argument required " % (arg,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `classmethod` to create an instance only if the passed value is a string:

```
class Stage:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
  @classmethod
  def stage(cls, arg):
    return None if not isinstance(arg, str) else cls(arg)

s = Stage.stage("name")
```

Now, `s` will either be instance of `Stage` if `arg` is a string or `None` if `arg` is any other type.